# Как открыть барузер по умолчанию?

Tags: c#

Скажите, вот у меня есть переменная типа string, в ней хранится URL, а при нажатии на PictureBox, открывался браузер по умолчанию с ссылкой, которая была указана в переменной.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var process = new Process {StartInfo = {FileName = url}};
process.Start();
```